# Function error some changes need can'tt find a way

Tags: c, function, matrix

i have this fuction that count the number of pieces of the other color are between of the pieces of the same color. The problem is when i have something like this

o x . . . . . .

this is a line of the matrix and when I am playing with the x color. The function return that is possible or for others that i>0 but thats wrong should return 0 because can't find another x

x o x .  . . . .

like this will be a valid play and i>0

need some help doing this change

```
int count_flips_dir(char board[8][8],int line, char col,int delta_line,int delta_col,char color){
    int i=0;
    if (delta_line+line<=7 && delta_line+line>=0){
        if (delta_col+col<=7 && delta_col+col>=0){
            if(board[line+delta_line][col+delta_col]=='.'){
                return i;
            }
            for(i=0;board[line+delta_line][col+delta_col]!=color;i++){
                if(board[line+delta_line][col+delta_col]=='.'){
                return 0;
                }
                line=delta_line+line;
                col=delta_col+col;
            }    
        }
    }
    return i;
        
}
```

Comment: It's always suspicious when a `for` loop doesn't use the iteration variable. Why aren't you using `i` in the loop?

Comment: The loop checks for the argument `color` on the board but the opposite player's piece is hard coded as `'.'`.

Comment: @WeatherVane the loop will stop when find the same color of the piece that you are playing that is the problem it should do it but when it can't find it, it just continue because the i is coded to be i++ so when it wrong still came out has good , need to change to when can't find the same color the return value shoud be 0. Need some help coding that

Comment: Start by printing each piece in the line you are testing, to make sure you are examining the right cells. When you find a 'piece' of interest, mark its location and break from the loop. Start another loop from that point and again mark a location and break from the loop. If you haven't found two markers, quit.

Comment: The problem is that it should only count and return a value above 0 if it find another piece of the same color and i don t know how to do that, and it should run a loop because thd number of pieces in the midle are not constant

Comment: That's what my last comment said. Find a piece of the matching colour, then find the next piece of the matching colour. Make a diagram of what you need to do on paper.

Comment: Thanks for the help i am dumb some times